# Convert char to POSIXct

Tags: r

this is my date to convert:
"16:00:00 CT 08 Apr 2018"

and this is my try:

```
x <- "16:00:00 CT 08 Apr 2018"
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
as.POSIXct(x, format = '%H:%M:%S %A %d %b %Y')
```

and it returns NA

Comment: `CT` is not an unabbreviated weekday as what `%A` stands for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `CT` as such in the `format`

```
as.POSIXct(x, format = '%H:%M:%S CT %d %b %Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove string `CT` and go further:

```
as.POSIXct(paste(unlist(strsplit(x," CT ")),collapse = ""),format='%H:%M:%S %d %b %Y')
[1] "2018-04-08 16:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: `Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'CT'`

Comment: Updated removing warning.